# Python count Null and not Null values in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
Date  Name
1995  Harry
1995  John
1997  NaN
1995  NaN
1998  Nina
1998  NaN
1997  Carrie
```

I need to count a NaN/(not NaN) values for each Date. So the output should be

```
Date Nan/NaN+notNaN
1995 1/3
1997 1/2
1998 1/2
```

I was trying with 
`df.groupby(['Date']).agg({'Name' : 'count'})`
but can i do the same with 
`df.groupby(['Date']).agg({'df.Name.isnull()' : 'count'})` or smth like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like that:

```
In [52]: df.groupby('Date').agg({'Name': lambda x: x.isnull().sum(), 'Date': 'count'})
Out[52]:
      Name  Date
Date
1995     1     3
1997     1     2
1998     1     2
```

Or you could do following:

```
In [60]: df.groupby('Date').agg({'Name': lambda x: x.isnull().sum().astype(str) + '/' + str(x.size)})
Out[60]:
     Name
Date
1995  1/3
1997  1/2
1998  1/2
```

Or with `format`:

```
In [62]: df.groupby('Date').agg({'Name': lambda x: '{}/{}'.format(x.isnull().sum(), len(x))})
Out[62]:
     Name
Date
1995  1/3
1997  1/2
1998  1/2
```